# How can I find specific files on an Android device with Firemonkey?

Tags: firemonkey, delphi-xe6

I am developing a basic MP3 player Android app with Firemonkey (Delphi XE6), where the MP3 files will get added to a SD Card (external), post-installation. Thus, I need my app to be able to search for these specific MP3 files, once the user has activated/opened the app on their device.

The code for the file search is fine, but my problem is where to save the files on the SD Card and how to find the folder/directory location in code.

The concept should be very simple, but Firemonkey is (seemingly) making this much harder than it is supposed to be.

Here is my File Search code:

```
var
sr : TSearchRec;
i : Integer;
Storage : String;
begin
  //List files found on SD Card on device only, for now
  Storage := TPath.Combine(TPath.GetMusicPath, '*.mp3');
  if FindFirst(Storage, faAnyfile, sr) = 0 then
    begin
      repeat
        listSessions.Items.Add(sr.Name);
      until FindNext(sr) <> 0;
    end;
  FindClose(sr);
 end;
```

All I want know is, for the love of all that is good and pure, WHERE do I point the search to? The above location does not provide any joy, nor is it the generic GetMusicPath result. I cannot really hardcode the directory path, because then this will only work on ONE android device. I need this to work generically across all android devices.

TPath.GetDocumentsPath, TPAth.GetMusicPath and all the others like it get me all kinds of god-forsaken locations, which I cannot even find in File Explorer. For instance, my "generic" Music location (which is the one I want to use) returns this path: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.embarcadero./files/Music.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

What the Help file advice is -- is to use this:

shStorage := TPath.Combine(TPath.GetSharedMusicPath, '*.mp3');

However, that simply puts it at a higher level in the emulated path...

i.e.   /storage/emulated/0/Music

Get ESExplorer and look under internal storage -- the Music folder would contain the file using the above...

Other wise it appears in:
/storage/emulated/o/Android/data/com.Your_Domain_ID.YOURPROGID/files/Music

Hope that helps anyone looking for this info.